# Inability to update a model in a loop without overwriting terms R

Tags: r, for-loop, model

I am writing a function in R that will fit generalized additive models, based on the mgcv library. Essentially, I want to model y by x plus any number of user-specified covariates. Since the number of covariates will vary, I thought that I could create a base model of y ~ x, then update the model with each additional covariate until I run out of terms.

The problem is that each iteration over-writes the previous covariate, i.e. the model is not adding terms, but replacing them. Code below should explain a little better.

```
library(mgcv)
x <- 1:100
y <- x^3 + rnorm(100)
## Create two covariates
covar1 <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=T)
covar2 <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=T)
## Create data frame (this is what the user of function would supply)
covariates <- data.frame(covar1, covar2)
## Create basic model
model <- gam(y ~ s(x))

## Add terms to model until all covariates are added
m <- 1
while(m <= ncol(covariates))
{
  model <- update(model, . ~ . + covariates[,m])
  ## Oh no, model has been overwritten in second iteration
  print(summary(model))
  m<-m+1
}
```

How do I add each term (preferably by covariate name) to a model without overwriting? From my reading, I believe that anova.gam returns p values analogous to type III ANOVA, so that the order of adding terms doesn't matter.

Comment: `model.updated <- update(model, . ~ . + covariates[,m])`?

Comment: But wouldn't that just overwrite the model when going from first to second covariate? I am interested in a model containing all covariates, the above example was one way I'd though of for adding all desired covariates to the model

Comment: I seem to not understand your problem. First of all, you should put your data in a data.frame and use the `data` argument of the model function. Also, maybe the `dredge` function in package MuMIn would be helpful to you.

Comment: Perhaps I can try to state the problem in a different way. The user may specify a mandatory number of covariates which should be added to the model. For example, there might be a gender and age covariate to add. I want to model y given x for many thousands of y, adding in this case gender and age to the model, as specified by the user of the function. The function needs to be flexible enough to add these mandatory covariates, which can range realistically from 0 to many (though not more than 10). From this I would then extract significant relationships and focus on those in future analyses.

Comment: That sounds dubious from a statistical point of view.

Comment: Why? This is a high-dimensional biological dataset (many thousands of variables, a few hundred samples) for which the majority of comparisons will not show a relationship, despite the dogma being that the two variables are related. Any variables that do show a relationship could subsequently be cross-validated or tested in a new test set. I'm not sure why that is so dubious, but welcome your comments. Certainly, plotting a histogram of unadjusted p values demonstrates a clear true positive signal.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this can be solved by using:         model <- update(model,as.formula(paste0(". ~ . + covariates[,",m,"]")))